# What is the word used for 'handheld'?

Tags: words

A handheld video game device E.g. PSP, DS

Comment: Pure translation is off-topic on this website.  Please check [this post on meta](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76/should-pure-translation-questions-be-allowed).

Comment: @Michelle. For translations you can try our Chat site. Alternatively there are online English-Japanese dictionaries available. Just do a google for them and choose whichever site fits you best.

Answer (score 4):

I know you specified for a video game device, but `携帯【けいたい】` actually means "portable" or "handheld".  It's just that in this era of technology, it's become synonymous with "cell phone".  Some examples:

- 携帯型【けいたいがた】　→　portable (style)
- 携帯品【けいたいひん】　→　hand baggage
- 携帯【けいたい】カメラ　　→　hand camera

Answer (score 0):

「ポータブル」(because... 'PSP' = 'Play Station Portable')